# Facebook graph api audience fbid does not accept

Tags: facebook, graph

I want to integrate the facebook audience sdk.Documents are very difficult to solve. I'm stuck in a place

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id=APP_ID,app_secret=APP_SECRET,access_token=ACCES

_TOKEN)
ad_account = AdAccount(fbid=FACEBOOK_ID)

params = {
    CustomAudience.Field.subtype: CustomAudience.Subtype.custom,
    CustomAudience.Field.name: 'My new CA',
    CustomAudience.Field.description: 'People who bought on my website',
}
audience = ad_account.create_custom_audience(params=params)
```

When I send reqeust on python The bottom warning comes to me. But Im sure my fbid is true I got the necessary permissions but still the same situation

```
Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "fbtrace_id": "HyhfMfSiw3S",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_xxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "code": 100
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the app access token you are using should have access to your facebook ad project.